# Check if Bank account is listed at least one time

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like this:

```
    table 1:
        ID BankAccount
        23  3343
        32  4343
        43  3421 

    table2:
        EmpId Bank
        23    234
        23    3343
        32    1321
        32    4343
        43    1111
        43    2222

Output:
Id  BankAcount  Bank
43  3421        1111
43  3421        2222
```

And I want to check if there are employees where the bank account in table 1 doesn't exist at least at one of the records in table 2.

I wrote this:

```
select distinct [ID],[BankAccount],[Bank]
from table1 as tb1
inner join table 2 as tb2 ON tb2.EmpId = tb1.ID
where tb1.[BankAccount] <> tb2.[Bank] 
order by  [ID]
```

But of course it gives me "23" and "32" id's as an error. How can I correct the check?

Thank's.

Comment: So, for your sample data, you expect *no* results? Could you maybe expand the sample with a bit more data and some expected results?

Comment: Here what is bankaccount in table1 and bank in table2

Comment: Mukesh - same thing but diffrent field name in table 1 and table 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.BANKACCOUNT,T2.BANK 
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.ID=T2.EMPID
WHERE T1.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT T1.ID FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.ID=T2.EMPID
    WHERE T1.BANKACCOUNT=T2.BANK
)
```

**See demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ceae/7

The inner query

```
    SELECT T1.ID FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.ID=T2.EMPID
    WHERE T1.BANKACCOUNT=T2.BANK
```

will give you the employees where the bank account in table1 exist in table2. Now you can use these records in `not in` condition to get your result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query I give you below can serve as a starting point (e.g. as a subquery for a larger query, if you do want the other columns also), providing I've understood your requirements correctly:

```
declare @t1 table (ID int not null,BankAccount varchar(17) not null)
insert into @t1(ID,BankAccount) values
(23,'3343'),
(32,'4343')

declare @t2 table (EmpId int not null,Bank varchar(17) not null)
insert into @t2(EmpId,Bank) values
(23,'234'),
(23,'3343'),
(32,'1321'),
(32,'4343')

select
    EmpId
from
    @t2 t2
        left join
    @t1 t1
        on
            t2.EmpId = t1.ID and
            t2.Bank = t1.BankAccount
group by EmpId
having MAX(t1.BankAccount) IS NULL
```

That is, for all rows in `t2`, we attempt to find a matching account in `t1`. We then group everything by `EmpId` and then see if we have a situation where *none* of the rows (for a particular `EmpId` value) were able to make such a match.